# How can I add a ICommand to an event from FrameworkElement?

Tags: c#, xaml, mvvm

How can I add an `ICommand` to an event from `FrameworkElement`?

Specifically I want to do the following

```xml
<ListView> <!-- Button, Windows or whatever element -->
    <my:EventToCommand 
        Name="PreviewMouseLeftButton"
        Command="{Binding Path=MyCommand}"
        CommandParameter="{Binding ...}" />
    <!-- Value, Element, etc.. -->
</ListView>
```

I want to implement my own solution, which is for educational purposes and I don't wish to use any third-party libraries (MVVM Light, Prism, etc)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to use Attached Behaviors. For demonstration purposes, say I wanted to implement the Button Double Click using MVVM and the ICommand pattern, here's the relevant code:

First, create a static class called ButtonBehaviors that looks like this:

```
public static class ButtonBehaviors
{
    public static object GetButtonDoubleClick(DependencyObject obj)
    {
        return obj.GetValue(ButtonDoubleClickProperty);
    }

    public static void SetButtonDoubleClick(DependencyObject obj, object value)
    {
        obj.SetValue(ButtonDoubleClickProperty, value);
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty ButtonDoubleClickProperty =
        DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached("ButtonDoubleClick", typeof (object), typeof (ButtonBehaviors),
                                            new UIPropertyMetadata(new PropertyChangedCallback(OnButtonDoubleClickChanged)));

    private static void OnButtonDoubleClickChanged (DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        var button = d as Button;
        if(button == null)
        {
            return;
        }

        var command = e.NewValue as ICommand;
        if(command == null)
        {
            return;
        }

        button.MouseDoubleClick += (o, ev) => command.Execute(button);
    }
}
```

(I'll explain in a sec)

Then, here's how you would use it:

MainWindow.xaml:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication3.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml" xmlns:WpfApplication3="clr-namespace:WpfApplication3" Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Grid>
        <Button Content="Button" 
                Height="23" 
                HorizontalAlignment="Left" 
                Margin="173,89,0,0" 
                VerticalAlignment="Top" 
                WpfApplication3:ButtonBehaviors.ButtonDoubleClick="{Binding ButtonDoubleClick}"
                Width="75" />
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Finally, the ViewModel:

```
public class ViewModel
{
    private ICommand _buttonDoubeClick;

    public ICommand ButtonDoubleClick
    {
        get
        {
            if (_buttonDoubeClick == null)
            {
                _buttonDoubeClick = new SimpleDelegateCommand(() => MessageBox.Show("Double click!!"));
            }

            return _buttonDoubeClick;
        }
    }
}
```

and just for completeness, since you said no third party dll's here's my SimpleDelegateCommand:

```
public class SimpleDelegateCommand : ICommand
{
    private readonly Action _action;

    public SimpleDelegateCommand(Action action)
    {
        _action = action;
    }

    public bool CanExecute(object parameter)
    {
        return true;
    }

    public event EventHandler CanExecuteChanged;

    public void Execute(object parameter)
    {
        if(_action != null)
        {
            _action();
        }
    }
}
```

In a nutshell what's happening is this: when you assign the Command to the attached property, the OnButtonDoubleClickChanged event gets raised, at which point we hook up to the button.MouseDoubleClick event.

Comment: Your answer seems excellent, but as I can generalize the event? or pass as parameter