# Design Patterns c# repository

Tags: c#, design-patterns, repository

I recently did a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11651745/816721) and his answer was a pattern called [Attached Behavior](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/johngossman/archive/2008/05/07/the-attached-behavior-pattern.aspx), now instead of asking how to do something every time, it would be better to ask Where I can find a list of design patterns available?.

"available" is a big term. what I look for are patterns available for application development in WPF, C# .NET3.5/4.0/4.5 technologies, if possible explained with examples and beyond the more common.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Costs $79 but well worth it IMHO: http://www.dofactory.com/Framework/Framework.aspx

It is very extensive, has the [GoF](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gang_of_Four_%28software%29) and [Head First](http://shop.oreilly.com/product/9780596007126.do), [Enterprise](http://martinfowler.com/books/eaa.html) patterns and many more, contains real-world examples and also more abstact examples and includes sourcecode for each-and-every pattern contained in the "package". And ofcourse it is targetted at .Net (as per your question) but is applicable to every other capable language.

Although the quality is not extremely high, it does offer good value for money IMHO.

Answer (score 0):

- You might be interested in [MVVM](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dd419663.aspx):

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/278901/MVVM-Pattern-Made-Simple

- And [Scafolding](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scaffold_%28programming%29):

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/36975/WPF-CRUD-Generator-Scaffolding

Comment: Not be be nitpicking, but how are those 2 suggestions "Design patterns repositories"? The first suggestion is just a single example of a design pattern and the second isn't a design pattern at all.

Comment: Take a look at the question: "... what I look for are patterns available for application development in WPF ..." First one is a pattern applicable to WPF, if rkmax wants complex examples, he can ask for them and community can answer. Second one, scaffolding, is a concept that @rkmax might find useful, since in his previous post mention educational purposes. By the way, did you read rkmax previous post: "... don't wish to use any third-party libraries ..." might be applicable for this too as well.

Comment: Design patterns are (quote from wikipedia): "a general reusable solution to a commonly occurring problem within a given context in software design". He is, as far as I'm concerned, explicitly asking for design patterns. Also, he won't need to actually use the "third party library" (which my suggestion isn't); it explains the *concepts* of the patterns and provides *samples* (both real-world and abstract (bare to the bones)) for them. No need to actualy use them. Attached behaviour (altough unknown to me but I'm assuming it to be similar to the Decorator pattern) is just another design pattern.

Comment: Ok, let's leave rkmax evaluate what's helpful for him... an answer that links to books of any kind of design patterns doesn't seem accurate for me. Have a nice day ;)

Comment: You are right, sir. Although I would like to add that my suggestion [**isn't** a (physical) book or books](http://www.dofactory.com/Framework/Framework.aspx#Table4). It is fully digital, completely downloadable. Just a bunch of PDF's with the patterns and their explanations and VS2010 projects containing the samples.